# Rotate a UIImage or UIView to a particular angle, NOT an amount of angle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, image-rotation

Objective-C for iOS.

How do I rotate an image or view TO a particular angle.
I have tried the two methods below, but both rotate the AMOUNT of angle, not TO the angle.
Basically I would like to call a method to rotate to 90' and then say call again of 180', and the image/view to finish at 180', NOT an addition of them both (270') which is what happens if I use either of the methods below.

```
#define degreesToRadians(degrees) (M_PI * degrees / 180.0)

myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(90));

myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(myImage.transform, degreesToRadians(90));
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reset by

```
.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
```

before the other transforms...

Answer (score 1):

ohho's answer can be useful if you haven't to do animation. 
I found useful this trick:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            self.compassImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, radians);
        }];
```